# DelayedExpansion variable does not expand within FOR loop

Tags: command-line, batch

I have a FOR loop that makes a single string out of every line in a file. The idea is that for each line, there's a parallel line in a secondary file with a variable value in it. I've made here a loop that echoes the variable it reads just for testing purposes.

```
for %%a in (!loadstream!) do (
    set /A "linecount=!linecount!+1"
    for /F "skip=!linecount!" %%i in (save\%1\%1.sav) do (
        echo %%i
    )
)
```

The first FOR works fine, but the one within it does not expand the variable. Rather, it stays as !linecount! and gives `!linecount!" was not expected at this time.` It works fine if you put in `%linecount%` instead but I need that variable to count one up every time it loops, so that's a no go. `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is set, of course.

This block of code is meant to be called within a script whenever a certain set of variables needs to be loaded. I could try and build a clunky workaround but I can tell that this is the way to do it, and I just don't understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `cmd` doesn't expand whatever is in the options field of `for /f`; as a work-round I tried using a loop variable `for /f "skip=%%n" ...` and this also fails to expand.

The only solution I've found is to do the skip yourself:-

```
for %%a in (!loadstream!) do (
    set /A linecount=!linecount!+1
    set lineno=0
    for /F "delims=" %%i in (save\%1\%1.sav) do (
        set /A lineno+=1
        if !lineno! == !linecount! echo i: %%i
    )
)
```

I added the `"delims="` option to force reading whole lines, since I was testing on arbitrary files with blanks in the lines; this will have no effect if your files have no blanks, but omit it if you want only the first field from each line, so that the other fields will go into `%%j`, etc.

Comment: Works flawlessly! I would have never thought of doing this. Thanks!